# Boost Unit Test Framework: How to show a per test suite message

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Say, I have many test suites attached to the master suite. They run turn by turn. How to print a text message before each suite starts running? If I do it in initialization functions, everything is printed at the very beginning, before any suite starts running. If I do it inside a test function, the message may appear multiple times. There should be some macro or something else specifically designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the value of [log_level](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html):

- all - report all log messages including the passed test notification
- success - the same as all
- **test_suite** - show test suite messages
- message - show user messages
- warning -report warnings issued by user
- error - report all error conditions
- cpp_exception - report uncaught c++ exception
- system_error - report system originated non-fatal errors (for example, timeout or floating point exception)
- fatal_error - report only user or system originated fatal errors (for example, memory access violation)
- nothing - do not report any information

Comment: log_level=test_suite reports every test case in every test suite. I am getting hundreds of pages of all sorts of messages. I played with other switches too. No success yet.

Comment: @Watson: I'd consider just editing the boost::test source at that point. Easy to leave the logging on test_suite but to comment out the line in the source that emits the per-test messages.

Comment: For the time being, you can simply add a test case in front of your test suite, which prints the message you wants.
Otherwise this could have been done in per-test-suite fixture, but Boost.Test does not support it yet.